# Restrict LINQ Subquery when databound to a grid

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to limit the number of child elements I get back.  In this example Order.CustomerID "VINET" has 3 Order Details.  I only want to see the record that has a unit price of 14.  I do NOT want to see the Order Details where the unit price equals 9.8 or 43.8

In the end I want to do this in a dynamic where query or with a predicate, but the simple example should show my problem.  I tried this a couple of different ways including the two i have shown below.  I realize the problem is in the fact that LINQ is automatically running its own queries when I expand, but does anyone have a good solution?

```
private void btnJoinProblem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var tempQ2 = (from od in db.Order_Details   
join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
where od.UnitPrice == 14
select o).Distinct();
}
```

Also brings back too many subrecords at the Order Detail level

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var tempQ = from o in db.Orders 
            where o.Order_Details.Any(od => od.UnitPrice == 14) 
            select o;

var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = tempQ;
ultraGrid1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I'd do is "select" the columns that you want into an anonymous type (or a named type) - this means you are getting rectangular data, and you don't have to worry as much about lazy loading. Secondly, you need a list for the grid.

Try something like:

```
using(NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext()) {
    var query= from od in db.Order_Details   
               join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
               where od.UnitPrice == 14
               select new {o.OrderId, o.Customer.CustomerName,
                          od.UnitPrice}; // etc

    ultraGrid1.DataSource = query.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: BindingSource.DataSource accepts around 10 different types. IEnumberable is one of them. You only need list if you want to use the add/delete functionality.  :)

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to build my own custom objects since the lazy loading is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to a `BindingSource` and using `AsDataView()` on your query and see if that works, like the following:

```
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = tempQ.AsDataView();
```

Of course, don't forget to set the grid's data source to the `BindingSource`.

A quick note: `AsDataView()` cannot be used if there's a join. IIRC, the following *should* work though:

```
var tempQ = from o in db.Orders
            where o.Order_Details.Any(od => od.UnitPrice == 14)
            select o;
```

Note that you probably want to use the child relation o.Order_Details, not db.Order_Details, (assuming it's set up correctly in your dataset).

Comment: I get these errors
Instance argument: cannot convert System.Linq.IQueryable<DAL.Order> to System.Data.DataTable
&
does not contain a definition for 'AsDataView' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsDataView(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: PS I added a ref to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll so that is not my problem.  I am grateful for the quick answer.

Comment: var tempQ2 = (from od in db.Order_Detailsjoin o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderIDwhere od.UnitPrice == 14select o).Distinct();

Comment: msdn says I can't use a join with AsDataView()

Comment: I did it your way and that also brings back too many order details.  I appreciate your time on Saturday.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused then, the query I suggested returns all orders which have an order detail where UnitPrice is 14. When you go to retrieve the child order details, you're going to have to filter again. How are you displaying the order details? On another grid?